# Connection count in ICE

Tags: java, ice

Now I am trying to use ICE in a java project. I wonder whether I should config the connection count for both server and client. If I should, how can I config the count?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should do this.

> Each communicator creates two thread pools:
>
> The client thread pool services outgoing connections, which primarily
>   involves handling the replies to outgoing requests and includes
>   notifying AMI callback objects. If a connection is used in
>   bidirectional mode, the client thread pool also dispatches incoming
>   callback requests. The server thread pool services incoming
>   connections. It dispatches incoming requests and, for bidirectional
>   connections, processes replies to outgoing requests. By default, these
>   two thread pools are shared by all of the communicator's object
>   adapters. If necessary, you can configure individual object adapters
>   to use a private thread pool instead.

The number of threads is only one by default. So you may want to enlarge it.

Change these numbers in three ways:

1. command line arguments
2. hard code
3. config file

**Hard Code example**:

```
protected void initProperties(Ice.Properties iceProperties) {
    iceProperties.setProperty("Ice.Override.ConnectTimeout", "70");
    iceProperties.setProperty("Ice.ThreadPool.Client.Size", "100");
    iceProperties.setProperty("Ice.ThreadPool.Client.SizeMax", "1000");
    iceProperties.setProperty("Ice.ThreadPool.Client.StackSize", "131072");//128k
    iceProperties.setProperty("Ice.ThreadPool.Server.SizeMax", "1000");
    iceProperties.setProperty("Ice.ThreadPool.Server.StackSize", "131072");
    iceProperties.setProperty("Ice.MessageSizeMax", "102400");
}

protected void init() {
    Ice.Properties iceProperties = Ice.Util.createProperties();
    initProperties(iceProperties);
    Ice.InitializationData initData = new Ice.InitializationData();
    initData.properties = iceProperties;
    ic = Ice.Util.initialize(initData);
    communicators.add(ic);
}
```

See this:

- http://doc.zeroc.com/display/Ice/Using+Configuration+Files
- http://doc.zeroc.com/display/Ice/Thread+Pools